# EF Code-First migration not detecting changes

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I have a database in which I needed to introduce a new required FK relationship between two existing tables. Since they both have existing data (and the product is already running in production), I needed to take some more steps to add the new columns and FK relation.

The first migration added a new, nullable `Guid` column to an existing table which was to be the principal column in the FK relation. Then using a custom SQL script I updated the records in the table with the corresponding values from the other table.
I then updated the model, making that same `Guid` non-nullable and generated a new migration, which also added an index to the column.

All is well up to here.

I then configured the FK relationship in both model's configurations and generated a new migration. This migration, however, seems to refuse to pick up the changes to the model and configurations.

Below are the model definitions and corresponding configurations.
The properties of interest everything to do with `Registry`.
**Company**

```cs
public class Company
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the unique identifier of the <see cref="Company"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name of the <see cref="Company"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the unique identifier of the <see cref="Group"/> to which the <see cref="Company"/> belongs.
    /// </summary>
    public Guid? GroupId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the unique identifier of the <see cref="Registry"/> from which the <see cref="Company"/> entity was created.
    /// </summary>
    public Guid RegistryId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the date and time at which the <see cref="Company"/> was created.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; } = DateTime.UtcNow;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the unique identifier of the user who created the <see cref="Company"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public Guid CreatedBy { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the date and time at which the <see cref="Company"/> was last updated.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a concurrency token used to prevent conflicting edits in a <see cref="Company"/> entity.
    /// </summary>
    [SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "PropertyCanBeMadeInitOnly.Global", Justification = "Used by Entity Framework.")]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; } = null!;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the <see cref="Group"/> to which the <see cref="Company"/> is linked through <see cref="GroupId"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public Group? Group { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the <see cref="Registry"/> to which the <see cref="Company"/> is linked through <see cref="RegistryId"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public Registry Registry { get; set; } = null!;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a collection of <see cref="SystemIdentifier"/> linked to this <see cref="Company"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public ICollection<SystemIdentifier> SystemIdentifiers { get; set; } = null!;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a collection of <see cref="User"/> linked to this <see cref="Company"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; } = null!;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a collection of <see cref="Permission"/> linked to this <see cref="Company"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public ICollection<Permission> Permissions { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

**Registry**

```cs
public class Registry
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the unique identifier of the <see cref="Registry"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a token required to verify the <see cref="Registry"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public string? RegistrationToken { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name of the company to which the registered client belongs.
    /// </summary>
    public string? CompanyName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a JSON string containing a list of requested users.
    /// </summary>
    public string? RequestedUsers { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the specified user in the registry are handled.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsHandled { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a concurrency token used to prevent conflicting edits to a <see cref="Registry"/> entity.
    /// </summary>
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; } = null!;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the date and time at which the <see cref="Registry"/> was created.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the date and time at which the <see cref="Registry"/> was last updated.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a collection of <see cref="RegistryAgreement"/> entities linked to the <see cref="Registry"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public ICollection<RegistryAgreement> Agreements { get; set; } = null!;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a collection fo <see cref="Company"/> entities linked to the <see cref="Registry"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

**CompanyConfiguration**

```cs
public class CompanyConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Company>
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Company> builder)
    {
        builder = builder ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));

        builder.HasKey(c => c.Id);
        builder.Property(c => c.Id)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("NEWID()");

        builder.Property(c => c.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(75);

        builder.Property(c => c.RegistryId)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(c => c.CreatedAt)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()")
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(c => c.CreatedBy)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(c => c.UpdatedAt)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()")
            .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate()
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(c => c.RowVersion)
            .IsRowVersion();

        builder.HasOne(c => c.Group)
            .WithMany(g => g.Companies)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.GroupId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull)
            .IsRequired(false);

        builder.HasOne(c => c.Registry)
            .WithMany(r => r.Companies)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.RegistryId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.HasMany(c => c.Permissions)
            .WithOne(p => p.Company)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.CompanyId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction)
            .IsRequired(false);

        builder.HasMany(c => c.SystemIdentifiers)
            .WithOne(si => si.Company)
            .HasForeignKey(si => si.CompanyId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction)
            .IsRequired(false);
    }
}
```

**Registry**

```cs
public class RegistryConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Registry>
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Registry> builder)
    {
        builder = builder ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));

        builder.HasKey(r => r.Id);
        builder.Property(r => r.Id)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("NEWID()")
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(r => r.IsHandled)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
            .HasDefaultValueSql("0")
            .HasColumnType("bit")
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(r => r.CreatedAt)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()")
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(r => r.UpdatedAt)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()")
            .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate()
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(r => r.RowVersion)
            .IsRowVersion();

        builder.HasMany(r => r.Agreements)
            .WithOne(ra => ra.Registry)
            .HasForeignKey(ra => ra.RegistryId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

        builder.HasMany(r => r.Companies)
            .WithOne(c => c.Registry)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.RegistryId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
    }
}
```

I tried some posted solutions on other, similar questions on StackOverflow, but none seemed to work. Here is what I tried:

1. Simply add another migration.

   - This wouldn't work, as the migration doesn't pick up the new migration.
2. Run `Update-Database` on second-to-last migration, then remove and overwrite last migration.

   - I figured this might work, as it would have to pick up on the changes made in the previous migration as well. However this also didn't work, it didn't even pick up the changes from the last migration.
3. Run `Update-Database` on second-to-last migration, remove last migration, delete changes in snapshot, then create new migration.

   - This resulted in Entity Framework throwing an error, saying it couldn't find a navigation property, even though it was clearly defined in the model, configuration *and* the snapshot as this was not a change introduced by any of the migrations I created for this new FK relationship.

I spent a whole workday on this issue, and decided to post this question before continuing to waste another workday.

I realise this question has been posted a fair few times, so if there's another question here that has the right answer, feel free to mark this as possible duplicate!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you are not using one tag to many? I would assume you are not both using EF Core & EF 6. In any case, I would suggest trying to create a minimal reproducible example. Create a new project with two simple tables, and try recreate what you are trying to do. That might help isolate the issue, or at least make it easier to ask about. It might also be useful with a easy way restore a clean slate, i.e. revert all the code, drop database, and recreate.

Answer (score 1):

May be You forgot to apply your entity configurations to OnModelCreating method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    new CompanyConfiguration().Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<Company>());
    new RegistryConfiguration().Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<Registry>());
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you Fabio, good question! My migration should however be automatically detected and applied through this line `modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(PortalDbContext).Assembly);`.